# semicolon after curly braces in c++

Tags: c++, vtk

I have recently started working with the vtk package and I see this odd notation that they include `;` after closing curly braces `}`. Here is an example from `vtkUnstructuredGrid.h`

```
// Description:
// Standard vtkDataSet API methods. See vtkDataSet for more information.
int GetDataObjectType() {return VTK_UNSTRUCTURED_GRID;};
```

It's not needed and QtCreator also correctly detects this by saying `extra ;` when parsing the code. I'm curious what could be the reason for this? Maybe readability?

Comment: Zero reason whatsoever. Extraneous semicolon is extraneous (and causes compiler warnings).

Comment: Autogenerated code perhaps?  It may simplify the logic a bit (kind of like adding an extra `,` to the last value in an enum), hard to say.

Comment: @EdS. hummm maybe. I remember CMake was generating some of the files at the compile time ...

Comment: @JesseGood I compiled with 2.8

Comment: I'll confess that I often put in these extraneous semi-colons because they 'mirror' (for want of a better word) the semi-colon that's necessary if you don't inline the function body.  I'll also confess that I'm definitely not consistent with using (or not using) them.

Comment: @Michael Burr: that makes no sense. You need either one or the other (depending on whether it's a function definition or just a function declaration) but not both.

Comment: Maybe someone gets paid by "lines of code" and the line counting program counts semicolons.  So they are generating revenue.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: you need one if it's a declaration, but having one if it's a definition is harmless.  Note that I do this only for inlines inside a class declaration, and it's not because I prefer it. They probably end up there more from turning a non-inline into an inline and just not getting rid of the semi-colon that's already there.  Or something.  I'll have to try to pay more attention next time I catch myself doing it.  This comment thread is already far more reflection on this than I've ever done before...  (I've never noticed a compiler or tool warn about it, either).

Comment: @Michael : GCC warns with `-Wpedanitic` I think. :-]

Comment: A semicolon following a function definition is a syntax error.  The function definition ends with the closing `}`.  Inside a function, a bare semicolon would be parsed as a null statement; outside a function, statements are not permitted, so there's no correct interpretation.  (g++ isn't a fully conforming compiler by default; with `-pedantic` it warns about this.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: the following is not a syntax error: `class foo { void bar(){} ; };`  The first semi-colon is extraneous - it's called out in the C++ grammar as an optional item following a *function-definition* in a *member-declaration*.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: You're right, I didn't know that. I wonder why they made it optional. Seems to me it just adds to the confusion.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, yes, you _can_ use both for a member function definition in class-scope, but you don't _need_ both, and you _can't_ use both for a namespace-scope function definition. IMHO it makes more sense for class-scope function definitions to "mirror" namespace-scope definitions than to "mirror" member function declarations.  I maintain your rationale makes no sense ;-)

Comment: Isn't this a question for the vtk user mailing list? http://www.vtk.org/VTK/help/vtkusers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As QtCreator correctly detects, *that* is definitely an extra semicolon that not only is useless, but can also cause compiler warnings and confusion.

For example GCC with the `-Wpedantic` flag [will trigger](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95a272dfbb6e6430):

> warning: extra ';'

Answer (score 0):

Its not that uncommon. In C++, a statement is ending with a `;`. So the statement is `int GetDataObjectType();`. 
Now, this statement is a function and it also has a block defined: `int GetDataObjectType() {};` inside the block, we have another statement: `return VTK_UNSTRUCTURED_GRID;` so the complete line may have an extra semicolon, but its not a semicolon too-much, it is just a semicolon you *may* omit.